# how to save file in relative path using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, save, filepath

I want to save .json file in application path using javascript.
I used the following code to save the file. but it saved in physical path. not in the application path.
**my code is:**

```
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 var s = fso.CreateTextFile("E:\\Model.json", true);
 s.WriteLine(json);
 s.Close();
```

in server side can use **Server.MapPath**  but i dont know how to save in Javascript.
please guide me friends,
thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you intend to run this script inside a webpage? I doubt if it would work that way.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're running this via Windows Scripting Host or similar.

Just use a relative path:

```
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("Model.json", true);
```

Note I left the `E:\\` off.

I don't know what you mean by "*the application path,*" but that will save the file in the current directory in which the script/application is running. If you want to do it relative to one of the "special" Windows folders, use [`FileSystemObject#GetSpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a72y2t1c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the special folder's path, then append your path to it.

Comment: I could read the file by calling Model.json.. but i cant save the file.

Comment: @ganesh: Then it's nothing to do with the code. I just grabbed your code, removed the `E:\\`, created a `json` var, and ran it using Windows Scripting Host. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just strip the drive prefix amd use relative path?

```
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

 var s = fso.CreateTextFile("MyFolder\\Model.json", true);

 s.WriteLine(json);
 s.Close();
```

And also, from looking at the [FSO documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) there are several ways to obtain the current directory path and compute the path yourself as well.